# Only the last element of the array is displayed

Tags: java, arrays, dynamic-arrays

Only the last element of the array is filled; when a new element is added to the array, the old element becomes null.

```
public void SelectClick(View view) {
 ...
    materialCardView.setId(secondId);
    arrayPath = new String[secondId + 1]; //in class declaration String[] arrayPath = new 
String[secondId];
    //+ 1 needed in order not to get an error ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
    showFileChooser(); //calls method leer (внизу)
 ...
}

public void leer() {
    arrayPath[secondId] = FilePath; FilePath = ""; //the path that should fall into the array is supplied
    secondId++; //without this, the first element of the array overwrites itself and does not go further
 ...
}
```

With this code, the log displays the first element `I/System.out: [test]`, and when the next element of the array is added (pressing the button, the SelectClick method), it displays `I/System.out: [null, test]` and so on, always only the last element is not null. What to do?
//comments changed to English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### ArrayList

Since your array is constantly extending, don’t use a fixed-size array. Use an `ArrayList`.

```
    List<String> arrayPath = new ArrayList<>();
    arrayPath.add("test1");
    arrayPath.add("test2");
    System.out.println(arrayPath);
```

Output:

> [test1, test2]

### What went wrong in your code?

The trouble is in this line:

```
    arrayPath = new String[secondId + 1];
```

This creates a new array with all `null` elements, throwing away all the contents that were previously in the `arrayPath` array.

To demonstrate:

```
    String[] arrayPath = { "test1" };
    int secondId = 1;
    
    arrayPath = new String[secondId  + 1];
    arrayPath[secondId] = "test2";
    secondId++;
    
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayPath));
```

> [null, test2]

If you insist on using an array, you may use the `Arays.copyOf` method for creating a new and longer array holding all the old elements in it:

```
    arrayPath = Arrays.copyOf(arrayPath, secondId + 1);
    arrayPath[secondId] = "test2";
    secondId++;
```

With this change the output is:

> [test1, test2]